# MC Journey builder: Filtering on the attributes of the source data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to set up a synchronized data extension. So far, I successfully receive data from the Sales Cloud and then query that data into a sendable data extension using a SQL Query Automation.

However, when I try to use this data extension as entry source of a journey, I'm unable to filter the data correctly:
I cannot filter using the attributes of my data extension, instead I am presented with filter options on the attributes of the synchronized objects, which don't seem to work - the contacts aren't injected into the journey, even though they meet the criteria.

Is there a way to filter directly on the attributes of the data extension?

Edit: I'm unable to pick Journey data attributes as filter criteria
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Journey data is the information about a contact that is brought in
>   when the contact enters a journey. It’s like a snapshot of the
>   contact’s attribute data at the moment the contact is added to the
>   journey.

Source : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_entry_control_best_practices.htm&type=5

In other words, when you are at the entry point level, the Contact Data are the same as the Journey Data. That's why you can't select "Journey data" in the filter part of the data extension entry point.

To achieve what you want, you have two options :

Option 1 - If you want to filter in the data extension entry point :

-> In order to filter on your data extension at this step, you need to link your data extension in the data designer. You can find here the steps for doing that.
-> This is the reason why you can see your Syncrhonized Data Extension : when the MC Connect is set up, the synchronized data extensions are automatically linked in the data designer.

Option 2 - Use the Journey Data :

-> In order to use a Journey data, you need to create a desicion split. What you can do is to not filter the contacts at the entry point level, but add a decision split as the first step of your Journey.

You will then be able to use the Journey data :

[image]

From my side, I think the option 1 should be the one advice by Salesforce. I think it's better for the KPI analysis of the Journey. 
With the option 2, every contact that are in your Sync. Data Extension will enter to the Journey and the majority of these contacts will probably go the reminder part of the first decision split.

I hope it helps you !

Comment: Thank you for the valuable insight. I was able to solve the issue using the first approach you suggested.

Comment: I tend to disagree - as Contact Data is referencing your Contact Builder data model, and not only the data included in the entry data extension. Hence "Contact Data are the same as the Journey Data"-statement is not entirely accurate, as the entry data extension can be updated via API, not using any of the other data in your instance.

Comment: This statement is only true at the entry point level.
When a subscriber is entered in the Journey, Contact data (-> content of the entry data extension) is not "equal" to Journey data because the data of the data extension can be updated indeed.
That's the reason I started my sentence in my response with "when you are at the entry point level". Do you agree ? I don't want to say something inaccurate :)

Comment: It is not given, that your entry DE is part of the contact model, and/or updated via the same route as the rest of your data model. Hence there can be discrepancies between journey and contact data - even at entry time.

Comment: It depends on your Contact model configuration indeed. If you create a link directly between your Contact Key attribute and the data extension, the data will be the same at the entry point.